# Index Out of Range in self Error - PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I am building a recommendations engine, using Pytorch under the hood (deep neural networks). Now, that I have a good model, I am trying to generate a table with predictions between user and content like-ability (affinity-score).

My Input Table of historical interactions

```
user_id | content_id
1       | 23
1       | 20
2       | 34
```

Then, I am converting these columns into tensors:

```
users=input['user_id].to_list()
content=input['content_id].to_list()

#convert to tensors
user_id_tensor = torch.tensor(user_id)
content_id_tensor = torch.tensor(content_id)

#prediction using historical data input on the trained model object
prediction = model.forward(user_id_tensor,content_id_tensor)

Error: Index out of range in self
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Can you give more information about your model?

Comment: Also, please provide the full error trace

Comment: @CuCaRot this is the doc: https://pypi.org/project/collie-recs/